# Switching to AHCI causes somewhat bricked (?) dell xps 9350

Tags: 16.04, dell, startup, bios, xps

I was looking to dual boot Windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a dell xps 9350. gparted/ubuntu was unable to detect the drive to commence an install (live usb worked great), so it was suggested to load bios and switch to AHCI.

Now the system does not start at all - the keyboard lights up, and the backlight for the screen, but nothing appears.

Cannot boot back to live USB, windows recovery USB not working - do I need to do a bios over USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix for this is as follows:

- in this instance the BIOS is NOT starting at all, so you have limited options.
- Open case, remove battery and CMOS battery, which fill force a BIOS reset.
- Case is tricky, see service manual here which notes that there are clips (and a screw near the service tag in the middle). 
  http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/xps-13-9350-laptop/xps-13-9350-laptop-v1/Before-working-inside-your-computer?guid=GUID-5D3B1051-9384-409A-8D5B-9B53BD496DE8&lang=en-us
- Once BIOS was reset, switched to AHCI with secure boot OFF - this allowed gparted/ubuntu to read the drive.
- From here you can do an install - see my other answer or msg if you need assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and found that Dell has a procedure to access BIOS anyway: hold down **Fn** key and turn computer on. 
That leads you to a test screen, from where you can access BIOS and change whatever setting you need to.
[Here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/266435#2) you can find it.

Comment: Interesting! That would have saved a lot of time and risk (of voiding warranty or further damage). Hopefully it is of use to someone in the future.